# GameKit not showing with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, game-center

From what I have seen, by adding:

```
.onAppear {
     GKAccessPoint.shared.location = .topLeading
     authenticateUser()
     GKAccessPoint.shared.isActive = true
}
```

and

```
func authenticateUser() {
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = { vc, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

on my main screen, game center should show the login button, the notifications and keep a logged in icon you can click to access the game center screen. And it has worked.. for a while.

However, suddenly it stopped, the login, notifications and buttons still work, but when I click the logged in game center icon, the game kit screen only appears for a millisecond and is automatically dismissed.

I am receiving these errors when I click the icon:

```
Cannot add page fields because none are specified by the metrics fields context. Did you forget to add an PageMetricsPresenter to the object graph used for actions?

Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomainCode=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>

[com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterDashboardExtension(1.0)] Connection to plugin interrupted while in use.
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Your function ```authenticateUser``` completes asynchronously. So it is probably better to set the access point to active in the authenticateHandler (in other words, on completion), rather than immediately after triggering authentication as you are doing in your example code. See the answer to [SwiftUI Game Center authentication doesn't prompt user to login](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64242914/20386264) for an example. BTW, when the player taps the access point and navigates to the leaaderboards, there appear to be some display issues in iOS 17.2. I already sent feedback to Apple about this.

Comment: For me it doesn't really mater, since I want the button to show wether it is a "log in" button or the user's avater. Nevertheless, I have moved `GKAccessPoint.shared.isActive = true` to the callback, but unfortunatelly it did not make a difference.

Also, my issue is not with the login view (which works), but with the game center interface (where leaderboards, friends and achievements are shown). Therefore, presenting the vc I get in the authentication callback would not really help.

Comment: The device is on iOS 17.1.1

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the achievements. I have deleted them, logged out and in, and now it works again. Still getting most of the errors, but not the one that says `Connection to plugin interrupted while in use` anymore

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did u solve it?

Comment: yes, by removing the achievements and creating them again